# How can I limit the current on this circuit?

Tags: power-supply, current-limiting

I'm trying to overclock my PC and I'd like to limit the current without losing voltage (small drop ok).  I have a 12V/.3A water pump and an old 12V/1A nokia phone charger.

Would something like this simple circuit work? [image]

Comment: You cannot limit current through a circuit without also dropping voltage when hitting the current limit.

Comment: If you have a 12v pump and a 12v power supply, then the pump will only draw the current it needs. Your resistor is futile.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to limit current why would you put an additional resistor in parallel with the load. All that does is consume more current from the 12V supply and creates needless heat.

Just connect your load to the 12V supply by itself and be done with it. If your load is indeed 40 ohms then the net current draw by the load will be 300mA. The 12V source will supply the needed current and no more.

There is no need to waste energy and fully load the power source up to its full 1A capability.

By the way it is a common misconception that a power source must force its full rated current some place. Instead the 1A rating of your power source is the maximum rated current that the supply can deliver so you should limit any load on the supply to be no less than 12 ohms. Any load of greater than 12 ohms will simply draw less current from the power source.

Answer (score 1):

Let us modify your question as follows:

Q: I have a mains powered water pump that takes 1 A. I want to plug this into a mains wall socket in my house. The wall socket can supply > 10 A. What should I do?

A: You just plug it in!

The pump will draw what current it requires. The current is effectively limited by the "resistance" of the pump. (It's somewhat more complicated than that with motors because the current reduces as they get moving and speed up.)

The simplicity of this arrangement is why we use constant voltage AC power supplies for our factories, offices and homes and constant voltage DC power for vehicles, etc. We can connect as many devices as required in parallel onto the supply up to the maximum current allowed by the cable and fusing.

---

Back to your 12 V pump: if it draws 0.3 A at 12 V that's all it will draw no matter how much current your 12 A power supply is capable of (provided it can supply at least 0.3 A).